# Dompdf shows error after converting two html files into pdf inside a loop

Tags: php, pdf-generation, dompdf

The scenario is: I have a table tbl_filebox which contains the base info that is required to generate pdf files. From each of these records, i extracted the data for the html page, and my pdf has 8 pages. So, run it through a loop and generate the html files first.

```
$fileboxData = $fileboxModel->getFileboxData();
foreach($fileboxData as $fb){
    //code block to render 8 php files.
    $filename =$basePath.'/'.$fb['file_id'].'.html';
    file_put_contents($filename, $content);

}
```

After this in some other function call, i convert these html files into pdf file and store them in the same place.

```
public function convertHtmlToPdf(){
    $fileboxModel = new FileBoxModel();
    $fileboxData = $fileboxModel->getFileboxData();

    require_once(APPPATH."components/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
    $basePath = './filebox/';
    foreach($fileboxData as $fb){
        $basePath='./filebox/'.$fb['rendering_state'].'/'.$fb['file_id'];
        $html_file = $basePath.'.html';

        if(file_exists($html_file)){
            $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
            $dompdf->load_html(file_get_contents($html_file));
            $dompdf->set_paper("a4", "portrait" );
            $dompdf->render();
            $output = $dompdf->output();
            $file_to_save = $basePath.".pdf";
            if(file_put_contents($file_to_save, $output))
                unset($dompdf);
        }

    }

}
```

The Problem is... this loop is executed only twice. On the third time, an error is generated with the following message.

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'DOMPDF_Exception' with message 'Frame not found in      cellmap' in C:\wamp\www\test_project\components\dompdf\include\cellmap.cls.php on line 244
```

What am i doing wrong here. Plz Help!! Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there some content in the third document that could be causing a table overflow error (e.g. a table cell larger than the available page space)? That's what the error looks like. See here: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/98

Comment: Also, running through dompdf more than once *can* work, but you're more likely to run into problems (especially when using PHP < 5.4). If you can move your dompdf render to an external file and run it using `exec()` you'll see much better performance and overall resource usage.